# Sorting a dictionary by count value

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to sort the output of a dictionary by the third column, or more specifically the count of values that appear in the example results. For context, the original answer provide was here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23199901/666891. I was unable to derive an answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/73050/666891 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/613218/666891 therefore am asking here.

The original out put is produced from:

```
for k in ret.keys():
    print '%s %d' % (k,ret[k])
```

Which results in:

```
google com 1132
akamaiedge net 378
bing com 381
microsoft com 197
```

And tried:

```
x = ret.keys()
sorted(x,key=operator.itemgetter(3))
for k in x:
    print '%s %d' % (k,ret[k])
```

which results in:

```
google com 1132
akamaiedge net 378
bing com 381
microsoft com 197
```

And lastly tried:

```
for k in sorted(ret.keys(),key=operator.itemgetter(3),reverse=True):
    print '%s %d' % (k,ret[k])
```

Which resulted in a similar output to the first:

```
microsoft com 197
akamaiedge net 378
google com 1132
bing com 381
```

Additionally, the value of `ret.keys()` is:

```
['google com', 'akamaiedge net', 'bing com', 'microsoft com']
```

**Solution** for my specific scenario is:

```
for k in sorted(ret.keys(), key=lambda k:ret[k], reverse=True):
    print "{:15} - {}".format(k, ret[k])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to sort based on the values, then the `key` parameter should get a function which could give the value corresponding to the current key, like this

```
d = {'google com':1132,'akamaiedge net':378,'bing com':381,'microsoft com':197}
for key in sorted(d, key=d.get):
    print "{:15} - {}".format(key, d[key])
```

**Output**

```
microsoft com   - 197
akamaiedge net  - 378
bing com        - 381
google com      - 1132
```

Now, whenever the sorting algorithm picks up a key in the dictionary, it calls the `key` function, which is the getter function of the dictionary, which will give the value corresponding to the key. So, the value corresponding to the key will be used for the comparison.

**Note 1:** The problem with your last code is that, you are using `operator.itemgetter(3)`, which will get the element at index 3 in the key. Your keys are strings, so the fourth characters in the keys will be used for comparison. That is why the last example in your question shows

```
mic*r*osoft com 197
aka*m*aiedge net 378
goo*g*le com 1132
bin*g* com 381
```

Alphabetically `r > m > g`.

**Note 2:** The problem with your second example is that, sorted doesn't change `x`, it returns a new list. So, you are still using the unsorted `x` only.

Answer (score 1):

I'd stick with the solution originally [proposed by Burhan Khalid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23200167/771848) which utilizes [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import re
from collections import Counter

with open('input.txt') as f:
    c = Counter('.'.join(re.findall(r'(\w+\(\d+\))', line.split()[-1])[-2:]) for line in f)

for domain, count in c.most_common():
    print domain, count
```

It uses [`most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method which essentially sorts the dictionary items by value in a reverse order using `sorted()`. No need to do it manually.

FYI, here's how `most_common()` source code looks on python2.7:

```
def most_common(self, n=None):
    '''List the n most common elements and their counts from the most
    common to the least.  If n is None, then list all element counts.

    >>> Counter('abcdeabcdabcaba').most_common(3)
    [('a', 5), ('b', 4), ('c', 3)]

    '''
    # Emulate Bag.sortedByCount from Smalltalk
    if n is None:
        return sorted(self.iteritems(), key=_itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    return _heapq.nlargest(n, self.iteritems(), key=_itemgetter(1))
```